# How to install parquet-tools on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS without building from source

Tags: software-installation, apache2, compiling

I've seen:

- [Installing parquet-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53306327/installing-parquet-tools)
- [Cannot compile parquet-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39453805/cannot-compile-parquet-tools)
- [Could not transfer artifact (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Received fatal alert: protocol_version -> [Help 1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50946420/could-not-transfer-artifact-https-repo-maven-apache-org-maven2-received-fat)
- [maven project failed to execute "maven-thrift-plugin"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52362001/maven-project-failed-to-execute-maven-thrift-plugin)
- [How to install libthrift-dev on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53475712/how-to-install-libthrift-dev-on-ubuntu)

And a few more on installing `thrift`. I would really prefer not to build `thirft` and then `parquet-mr` from source. **All I want is `parquet-tools`.**

I'm on:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
$
```

---

### Things I've tried:

- Download source from [github](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr) and [apache](http://parquet.apache.org/downloads/)
- Try to build from source as described [here](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-tools) and [here](http://support.miritech.com/blog/how-to-install-configure-apache-thrift-in-ubuntu-16-04/). I get many different errors.
- Build from `master` or build from some release tags like `1.11.x`. Got various errors, e.g.

  ```
  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:process (default) on project parquet-generator: Error rendering velocity resource.
      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
      ...
  Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error rendering velocity resource.
      at org.apache.maven.plugin.resources.remote.ProcessRemoteResourcesMojo.processResourceBundles (ProcessRemoteResourcesMojo.java:1246)
      ...
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
      at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull (Objects.java:203)
      ...
  ```
- Install thrift using `sudo apt-get install thrift-compiler` (which installs `0.9.x`, which gives compilation errors while building `parquet-mr`)

  ```
  [DEBUG]   (f) arguments = [-c, thrift -version | fgrep 'Thrift version 0.12.0' && exit 0;
                        echo "=================================================================================";
                        echo "========== [FATAL] Build is configured to require Thrift version 0.12.0 ==========";
                        echo -n "========== Currently installed: ";
                        thrift -version;
                        echo "=================================================================================";
                        exit 1]
  ```
- Try to build `thrift` [from source](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/BuildingFromSource), I get some errors:

  ```
  checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/home/kash/vm_share/thrift-0.13.0':
  configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
  ```
- Tried to look for `0.12/13.0` of pre-built `thrift` but can't find it. [Looks like](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/pm/thrift-compiler) for bionic there is only `0.9.0`

Please! I just want to see the meta of a parquet file on command line.

Comment: @guiverc Updated the title. I assume it is correct now. Feel free to edit! Or tell me run some other command to provide more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally managed to compile from source.

#### TL;DR

1. Compile `trift` with `--host=x86_64`.
2. Use `apache-parquet-1.11.11` tag on parquet-mr repo instead of `master`.
3. Update trift dependency version from 12 to 13 in `parquet-mr/pom.xml` and add maven central repo (`codehaus` is dead):

```
+    <repository>
+      <id>mvnrepository</id>
+      <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
+    </repository>
...
-    <thrift.version>0.12.0</thrift.version>
+    <thrift.version>0.13.0</thrift.version>
```

---

```
# install dependencies as described here: https://thrift.apache.org/docs/install/debian.html

# install thrift from source
wget -nv http://archive.apache.org/dist/thrift/0.13.0/thrift-0.13.0.tar.gz
tar xzf thrift-0.13.0.tar.gz
cd thrift-0.13.0
chmod +x ./configure
./configure --host=x86_64 --disable-libs
sudo make install

# build parquet-tools from source
git clone https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-mr.git
cd parquet-mr
git checkout apache-parquet-1.11.11

# build only parquet-tools and it's dependencies
# had to skip tests because one failed
mvn package -pl parquet-tools -am -Plocal -Dmaven.test.skip=true

# Use
java -jar parquet-tools/target/parquet-tools-*.jar --help

# Or if you're lazy like me:
alias parquet-tools="java -jar $(realpath ./parquet-tools/target/parquet-tools-*.jar)"

parquet-tools -h
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with homebrew, if you're into that:

```
brew install parquet-tools
```

It worked for me (on 20.04LTS), but boy-howdy did it take a while and pull down a lot of stuff.

Comment: Then, the question becomes: "how do I install brew?"